# I need to get SaveFileDialog after sending SendKeys.SendWait("^s") but the code below doesnt work

Tags: c#, winforms

I want below code displays savefiledialog after sending SendKeys.SendWait("^(s)"); to notepad fil. but the code doesn't work, what is the problem?

```
IntPtr handle = FindWindow("Notepad", "15 - Notepad");
if (!handle.Equals(IntPtr.Zero))
{
    // activate Notepad window
    if (SetForegroundWindow(handle))
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        // send "Hello World!"
        SendKeys.SendWait("Hello World!");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        //to show savefiledialog
        SendKeys.SendWait("^(s)");
        // to enter save button on savefiledialog
        SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work' mean?

Comment: Above code works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

change 
     `SendKeysWait("^(s)");` 
to
     `SendKeysWait("(^s)");`
Also upon simulating the save call I found it opens the save diologue box but you are clicked on to the files name. So you can actully add

`SendKeysWait("filesname.txt");` to give it a name.

Then use `SendKeysWait("{TAB}");` to tab over so save is highlighted then enter `{ENTER}`.

This works for me.

```
            SendKeys.SendWait("(^s)");
            SendKeys.Flush();
            SendKeys.Flush();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            SendKeys.SendWait("filename.txt");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            SendKeys.SendWait("{Enter}");
```

If there is a file with the same name you will get problems. There is likely a better way to go about automating notepad operations. You could use file io stream to create and write to .txt files. Msdn does a pretty good job of covering this.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx

Comment: Also once you have saved a file, obviously the hot key `Ctrl + s` will just save it and it will not open a dialogue box. So if you are trying to do this with an existing file it won't work cause it is just saving over it. If there is no file then it has to give a name and this will work.

Comment: Really you should use the System.IO.File class or any other of the many methods there are to open, write, and save various file types.